# nodemon: not found on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app runs locally with no issues by its failing on Heroku
package.json

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.9"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web:node app.js
```

its returning the below error

```
sh: 1: nodemon: not found
```

Any help on how to make this work?

Comment: Change your start npm script to not use nodemon or add it as a dependency. I recommend the first option as you don't really want to use nodemon in production. Although I admit it's confusing why it's using the start script instead of your proc file

Comment: Perhaps your proc file is not named correctly? Or is not in the root app directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodemon` is installed globally on your machine that's why you are able to run it on your machine. When you are pushing it on Heroku it is showing the error because there is nothing like `nodemon`.

Also, Heroku doesn't need `nodemon` so just replace your start script:

```json
node app.js
```

and change your Procfile to this:

```
web: npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue.
You just have to remove nodemon from start script
It has to be iin this way;
`"scripts": { "start": "src/index.js", "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js" }`